# Style tag not working when added via js after removing another style tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that adds a style tag to the HTML body with some CSS rules to rewrite the style declared in the css, and another one to remove the style tags.
Adding the style works, and removing it too, but when I try to add a second style tag after the first has been removed, it does nothing (but if I add the first one again, it applies the first one without problem).
(To remove them find them in the DOM using the title I add in the second parameter of addStyleRule).

Edit: as it has been discussed in the comments, if the second style tag, containing different text, has the same title than the first one, it is correctly applied. This only makes the problem more confusing, as if the document could only have a style tag, but I've checked the MDN documentation [(here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style), and the only issue they warn about is possible overwriting errors if written in the wrong order (which doesn't apply here, because I remove the first one before adding the second, so it must be very difficult for them to conflict).

In this snippet, you can see that adding the style tag works:

```js
function addStyleRule(str, title){
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = str;
  if(title)style.title = title;
  document.body.appendChild(style);
 }
function removeStyleRule (title) {
  for (var i in document.body.children){
   var child = document.body.children[i] || '';
   if(child && child.tagName && child.tagName == 'STYLE'){
    if(child.title == title){
     document.body.children[i].innerHTML = '';
     document.body.removeChild(child);
    }
   }
  } 
}
addStyleRule(':root{--font-color:red}','a');
```

```css
:root{
--font-color:black;
color:var(--font-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>This is red.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in this one, you can see the that adding a second style after removing the first does not work. It adds a rule titled 'a', then removes it, then adds onther one titled 'b', but it does not work. If you press the button, it applies the first one again, and it works, even without removing the second, that stays there, being useless.

```js
function addStyleRule(str, title) {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = str;
  if (title) style.title = title;
  document.body.appendChild(style);
}

function removeStyleRule(title) {
  for (var i in document.body.children) {
    var child = document.body.children[i] || '';
    if (child && child.tagName && child.tagName == 'STYLE') {
      if (child.title == title) {
        document.body.children[i].innerHTML = '';
        document.body.removeChild(child);
      }
    }
  }
}
addStyleRule(':root{--font-color:red}','a');
removeStyleRule('a');
addStyleRule(':root{--font-color:limegreen}','b');
```

```css
:root {
  --font-color: black;
  color: var( --font-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>This should be limegreen.</div>
  <button onclick="addStyleRule(':root{--font-color:red}','a');">If we re-add the first one, it is applied</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone have any insight about why the second one doesn't work? Oh, and I have tried it without the css variables, and still doesn't work, so I know the problem isn't there.

Comment: You should be using the [CSS OM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information) for this. As you've found, dynamically created `style` elements won't trigger.

Comment: But, @ScottMarcus, they do trigger the first time, and they are 'un-applied' when removed, and if they are re-added, and its the first one, they trigger, too. Is the second one (and so on) only the one that doesn't trigger, or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: it's strange, but it works if you make the second title also `a` and not `b`

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I have noticed that, too. That makes me believe that I'm missing something of the DOM.

Comment: all the letters doesn't work ... only the `a` works

Comment: @TemaniAfif, only the 'a' works because it is the one that was used first: had I used a different tag, like "buttercream123", only that would work.

Comment: this is crazy ... let's wait for a JS wizard to get some explanation

Comment: I'm telling you, use the CSS OM to solve this problem.

Comment: @ScottMarcus solving the problem with a complete new way isn't always helpful ... there is a lot better way to do this but it's more intresting to understand what is happening here and why such behavior ... why the title attribute is affecting this and why it works in some cases?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I have not chosen thie method because I want to use this "gimmick", it's because it allows me to overwrite **only** some properties in a selector, and on top of that, i can undo it later. Doing that with the CSSOM is feasible, but requires more clutter so it may become buggy. Since what I'm trying to do works the first time, I think if I tweaked something it would work every time.